# List unique values in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I know that

```
df.name.unique()
```

will give unique values in ONE column `'name'`.

For example:

```
name    report  year
Coch    Jason   2012
Pima    Molly   2012
Santa   Tina    2013
Mari    Jake    2014
Yuma    Amy     2014

array(['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], dtype=object)
```

However, let's say I have ~1000 columns and I want to see all columns' unique values all together.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using a dictionary comprehension with `unique`:

```
pd.Series({c: df[c].unique() for c in df})
```

The resulting output:

```
name      [Coch, Pima, Santa, Mari, Yuma]
report    [Jason, Molly, Tina, Jake, Amy]
year                   [2012, 2013, 2014]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can using `set`

```
list(map(set,df.values.T))
Out[978]: 
[{'Coch', 'Mari', 'Pima', 'Santa', 'Yuma'},
 {'Amy', 'Jake', 'Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina'},
 {2012, 2013, 2014}]
```

After put into Series

```
pd.Series(list(map(set,df.values.T)),index=df.columns)
Out[980]: 
name      {Santa, Pima, Yuma, Coch, Mari}
report    {Jason, Amy, Jake, Tina, Molly}
year                   {2012, 2013, 2014}
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to have you results in a list you can do something like this

```
[df[col_name].unique() for col_name in df.columns]
```

out:

```
[array(['Coch', 'Pima', 'Santa', 'Mari', 'Yuma'], dtype=object),
 array(['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], dtype=object),
 array([2012, 2013, 2014])]
```

This will create a 2D list of array, where every row is a unique array of values in each column.

If you would like a 2D list of lists, you can modify the above to

```
[df[i].unique().tolist() for i in df.columns]
```

out:

```
[['Coch', 'Pima', 'Santa', 'Mari', 'Yuma'],
 ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
 [2012, 2013, 2014]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following. This gets all unique values from all columns in a dataframe into one set.

```py
unique_values = set()
for col in df:
    unique_values.update(df[col])
```

Comment: To get the values you should update this to unique_values.update(df[col].unique())